# Optimizing the sql with subquery with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Could somebody help me optimize this query? I have a table with huge data. Could somebody help me optimize without using sub query?

```
SELECT user_id, scheduled_on_date
  FROM
    (SELECT user_id, scheduled_on_date
     FROM `calls`
     ORDER BY scheduled_on_date DESC) AS cinner
  GROUP BY user_id
```

Output expected is:
What I need is the only rows of the users with their last scheduled_date for call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as follows

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.scheduled_on_date ,other_fields_max_per_group
FROM `calls` c
JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(scheduled_on_date) scheduled_on_date
     FROM `calls`
      GROUP BY user_id) AS cc
ON(c.user_id =cc.user_id AND c.scheduled_on_date =cc.scheduled_on_date)
```

Add compound index

```
ALTER TABLE calls ADD INDEX `test` (user_id ,scheduled_on_date )
```

If there you only want the greatest date and user id you can use only

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(scheduled_on_date) scheduled_on_date
FROM `calls`
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: If you only need `user_id` and `scheduled_on_date` you can remove the other query. Also you might want to add `GROUP BY user_id` to avoid having multiple rows for a user who has several records with the same `scheduled_on_date`.

Comment: @Vatev yes i got your point first query is for getting the greatest row per group

Comment: actually, i need all other fields as well. Also, this query is taking much longer than the previous query I posted.

Comment: @ashish can you post the query plan? Does it take a long time for only the inner query?

Comment: @ashish - it might take longer, but this is the way you need to do it if you want the values of the other fields to be meaningful. The indexing is important though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1.*
from calls c1 left join call c2 on c1.user_id = c2.user_id 
     and c1.scheduled_on_date < c2.scheduled_on_date
where c2.user_id is null;
```

If you wanted to optimize it further

- make sure you have index on (user_id,scheduled_on_date)
- get only the required columns